# How to push user list to the client in OpenFire?

Tags: instant-messaging, xmpp

I'v installed a OpenFire and then added some users. Now when I login to any user by Spark, I can't see list of other users event they're online. I've checked **show offline users** but no change.

How can I force OpenFire to push users list to the client?